# How to automate desktop application on touchscreen panel from laptop?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, panel, touchscreen, winappdriver

1] I am having touchscreen laptop and panel now I want to automate windows application present on panel by running test script on laptop.

Current case: HDMI cable connect both laptop and panel but then touch event on panel does not work so I am expecting
User should run test script on laptop and it should be connected with panel in such way that all touch event works on panel while execution of test.